# Google Test: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol with Visual Studio 2017 with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I am currently trying to link Google Test to create a test suite for my Visual Studio Project, but am unable to get it to properly link. 
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.11)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${SERVER_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${MESSAGE_HELPER_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${PROTOBUF_MESSAGE_INCLUDE_DIR})

file(GLOB MessageHelperLibraryTestCPPFiles "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB MessageHelperLibraryTestHeaderFiles "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")

add_executable (MessageHelperLibraryTests
    ${MessageHelperLibraryTestCPPFiles} ${MessageHelperLibraryTestHeaderFiles})


target_link_libraries(MessageHelperLibraryTests MessageHelperLibrary)

message(WARNING ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})
#set(GTEST_MSVC_SEARCH MT)

target_link_libraries(MessageHelperLibraryTests ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(MessageHelperLibraryTests ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(MessageHelperLibraryTests ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(MessageHelperLibraryTests MessageHelperLibrary)
add_dependencies(MessageHelperLibraryTests ProtoMessages)

#add_test(AllTestsInMessageHelperLibraryTests MessageHelperLibraryTests)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

With build errors.

```
[ERROR] LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl testing::InitGoogleTest(int *,char * *)" (?InitGoogleTest@testing@@YAXPEAHPEAPEAD@Z) referenced in function main
```

The output of `${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}` is `D:/Programming_Apps/googletest/build/googlemock/gtest/Release/gtest.libD:/Programming_Apps/googletest/build/googlemock/gtest/Release/gtest_main.lib` which is the correct location for these libraries, yet it still seems like it is unable to correctly find and link the library. The other project does not contain a main as that is also a library so I am not sure as to why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get it work by hard coding the library path however following the documentation from their [README](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest) and creating the required directories at CMake compile time worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add **gtest_main** & **gtest** to your target_link_libraries. It may work.

```
target_link_libraries(MessageHelperLibraryTests, LINK_PUBLIC gtest_main gtest)
```

I also suggest you use CMake Macro PROJECT_NAME to replace MessageHelperLibraryTests here. You can try this.

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}, LINK_PUBLIC gtest_main gtest)
```